# Users putting answers as comments

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a lot of instances where users will answer simple questions... as comments on the original question, not answers. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990980/summing-up-rows-in-a-dataframe-by-a-common-factor). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986836/dcast-for-huge-dataframe-r). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979696/can-someone-tell-me-why-r-is-not-using-the-whole-data-frame-for-this-chisq-test).

I know we discourage people from posting comments as answers, but shouldn't the opposite be discouraged too? It doesn't really matter for whoever is asking the question because they get an answer either way, but it does make things more difficult for everyone else. Someone searching for an answer to a similar question they have may not realize that these questions have already been answered, for instance. Thoughts?

Comment: FYI, since this instance was just a few hours ago, I left a comment to give the person with the correct answer a chance to post their own answer.